# Can custom content type contain @ ? Restful call with jersy client

Tags: rest, jersey, content-type, jersey-2.0, media-type

Trying to call restful service which accept only application/xxxx@1.0 as content type, and service also return their payload (binary stream) with this content type.

I am using jersey client to make call, I got the following error, does it means that jersey client does not support any content type with @ inside?

Thanks

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing media
>   type 'application/x-xxx-data@1.0'
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:92)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:60)
>       at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:179)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext$5.apply(InboundMessageContext.java:446)
>       ... 48 more Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Expected separator ';' instead of '@'
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HttpHeaderReader.nextSeparator(HttpHeaderReader.java:115)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HttpHeaderReader.readParameters(HttpHeaderReader.java:249)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HttpHeaderReader.readParameters(HttpHeaderReader.java:242)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MediaTypeProvider.valueOf(MediaTypeProvider.java:110)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:90)

Answer (score 0):

See [Media Type Specifications and Registration Procedures:
4.2.  Naming Requirements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4288#section-4.2)

> Type and subtype names MUST conform to the following ABNF:

> ```
>  type-name = reg-name
> ```

```
 subtype-name = reg-name
```

> ```
>  reg-name = 1*127reg-name-chars
> ```

```
 reg-name-chars = ALPHA / DIGIT / "!" /
                   "#" / "$" / "&" / "." /
                   "+" / "-" / "^" / "_"`
```

`@` is not one of the allowed characters. You could so `"application/xxx!#$&.+-^_1.0"` and it would work.

Flow to exception:

- [`GrammarUtil`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/GrammarUtil.java) maintains a list of [`SEPARATORS`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/GrammarUtil.java#L77)

  ```
    private static final char[] SEPARATORS =
        {'(', ')', '<', '>', '@', ',', ';', ':', '\\', '"', 
         '/', '[', ']', '?', '=', '{', '}', ' ', '\t'};
  ```

  Along with this list are lists of other type to complete the list of possible characters. The only characters actually used though, in the process are the `/` and `;` characters, which are the separators for media types, e.g. `application/json;charset=utf-8`
- The [first separator is set](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/MediaTypeProvider.java#L111) to `/`. The goal of processing the media type string is to get a `MediaType` instance with constructed like  `MediaType(type, subType, params)`, where `type` is `application`, `subType` is `json`, and `params` is a `Map` including `charset=utf-8`
- The characters are traversed until meeting the first separator `/` where [`nextSeparator('/')`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/HttpHeaderReader.java#L138) is called. That is fine as they match as expected. But when the next separator character `@` is reached, `nextSepartor(';')` is called, as is the expected next separator. A [`ParseException` is thrown](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/HttpHeaderReader.java#L145)

  ```
    if (c != getEventValue().charAt(0)) {
        throw new ParseException("Expected separator '" + c + "' instead of '"
                + getEventValue().charAt(0) + "'", getIndex());
  ```